Get text in selected cells in a table in an Outlook mail
I have a table in an incoming Outlook mail. I would like to get the selection.

With the below code I get the selection and all the text between.
I would also like to know if the selection is in a table or just two lines, as it could be both in my mails.
If I watch wdDoc.Application.Selection.Range, Outlook crashes when I try to expand it.
Sub TableItems()
    'outlook
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim olInsp As Object
    Dim wdDoc As Object
    Dim strText As String
    Set OutApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = Application.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem ' this is the mail that is open and selected
    With OutMail
        Set olInsp = .GetInspector
        Set wdDoc = olInsp.WordEditor
        strText = wdDoc.Application.Selection.Range.Text ' Selected txt
    End With
End Sub


Shouldn't it be Set OutMail = OutApp.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem ?

I don't fully understand the following sentence "I would also like to know if the selection IS in a tabel or just 2 lines, as it could be both in my incomming mails." Can you clarify?

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.selection.information for how to tell if the selection is in a Table.

@DecimalTurn   The content in the mail couls be normal text, or in a tabel

@DecimalTurn using  OutApp.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem or Application.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem is the same as it is run in Outlook

@TimWilliams thanks, but {if wdDoc.Application.Selection.Information(wdWithInTable) } throws Runtime error 4608 , but i found this solution, just count the tables
wdDoc.Application.Selection.tables.Count, gives 0 if the selection isNOT a table

Seems like Word VBA can't access a multi-cell selection:  https://superuser.com/questions/1811246/word-macro-insert-text-into-each-selected-cell-of-a-table#:~:text=It%27s%20not%20actually%20possible%20to%20access%20the%20various%20parts%20of%20a%20non%2Dcontiguous%20Select%20directly%20using%20VBA

When you are selecting 2 cells (one above the other) from a table inside an Outlook message, you'll indeed get the text from the cells in between. If you dig into the string you'll notice that the content of the cells is seperated by the control characters CR (13) and BEL (07) in ASCII. This means you split the string based on that sequence and return the first and last cells content to get the values of the 2 selected cells:

Dim MyArray As Variant
MyArray = Split(strText, Chr(13) & Chr(7))

Debug.Print MyArray(0)
Debug.Print MyArray(UBound(MyArray) - 1)



yes, that is ok ,but if i select 3 cell, it would be more comlicated. if you just select eg 3 cells and copy them, you only get the 3 cells content.

@JesperMartinSchumacher, if you are dealing with more than 2 cells in a table, you might be better off exporting the table from Outlook to Excel. The support for tables is much better there.
